# VMware player Ubuntu VM not starting

Tags: virtual-machine

I had a perfectly working Ubuntu 12.04 VM running in VmWare player with Windows 8 as the host OS. I sent the Ubuntu VM to sleep from the Ubuntu menu (not the suspend option in VMWare Player). When I wanted to resume work, I was unable to wake the virtual machine. I then copied the VM folder and ran it on a different PC with Windows 8 as the host OS. I choose "I copied it" as the option when VMWare player asked. Now it is stuck at the screen with "Ubuntu 12.04" and four dots that no longer animate.

Before various unsuccessful attempts, the VM was stuck at the screen with the text "starting virtual printing" or something like that.

I tried to create a blank VM with older VM's VHD as the new primary VHD but the same problem appears.

Answer (score 0):

In another askubuntu-question there was the following suggestion:
In this case it isn't a VM but it should work too.

> Just enter "e" after GRUB loads
>
> Then delete "$linuxgfxmode" from like the 3rd or 4th line down and
>   replace with "nomodeset"
>
> Winner almost everytime on 11.10 and 12.xx apparently.

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120096/ubuntu-hangs-at-purple-screen)